# Gradle project version property from Java source

Tags: build, gradle

In my application I maintain the 'user-frendly' version as a public String constant in the main class.

Is it possible to retrieve this variables in the build.gradle to set the version property of the project? Currently I have to do this manually, what of course can lead to problems.

Comment: You probably want to do it the other way around: set the version in  properties file and grab it from there.

Comment: Where would I put this properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way of maintaining "user-friendly" version would be `version.properties` file, stored in your source tree. E.g., under `src/main/resources`. Then you can load this properties file in Gradle script:

```java
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("src/main/resources/version.properties").toURL())
println(config.versionNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've plussed Nikita's answer, which is great.

But, firstly, `File.toURL()` is now deprecated.  Something like this would be preferable:

```
ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse( file("src/main/resources/version.properties").toURI().toURL());
```

Secondly, note **`file( ...`** here, not <del>`new File( ...`</del> if this line is to be included in `build.gradle`.  The former makes a `File` relative to the path of the root directory of your Gradle project and is in fact a method of [Gradle interface Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html). It's worth knowing that every method or property in `build.gradle` which appears to "come from nowhere" is in fact a method or property of an underlying, "invisible" Gradle `Project` instance.

If you put `new File( "src/main... ")` in `build.gradle` as in Nikita's answer you would in fact not notice any problems if running your Gradle task from a console with current directory the project/root directory... but (according to my experiments) if using the GradleTasks window in Eclipse, for example, you would then be creating a `File` path relative to the directory where Eclipse was running from... and this would give an error message saying "system cannot find the path specified".

Using `file( ...`, therefore, you can then go (in `build.gradle`):

```
version = conf.versionNumber
```

NB `version` here is another property of Project... but you'll be mystified if you look at the above Javadoc for `Project`, because it's not there! However, you **will** see `getVersion()` and `setVersion(...)`. With Groovy every property automatically gets given, by Groovy magic, its own getter and setter method. I took a week out to learn a bit of Groovy, which is actually a fantastic language, and familiarising yourself with it a bit is highly recommended, and makes the learning curve of Gradle substantially less painful.

You **can** however find the `version` property in the DSL (domain-specific language) API for Gradle class `Project` [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html).

The file `version.properties` would typically contain something like this:

```
versionNumber='1.0.0'
```

**NB accessing version from your code** ... if you wanted to access this version number from your app code (or test code), you *would* indeed use `new File( ...`:

```
ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse( new File("src/main/resources/version.properties").toURI().toURL());
```

as in Nikita's answer.